# Convert wff to pff ∃x[P(x)∧∀y[B(y)→L(x,y)]]

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

[image]

I'm doing an exercise in Mathematical Methods in Linguistics, Chapter 7, page 54.

The task is to convert ∃x[P(x)∧∀y[B(y)→L(x,y)]] to its Prenex Normal Form. I followed the laws and the steps given in the book and get the expected result. But it's still unclear to me how to solve such a question alone. I mean, I know that the ultimate goal is to move all the quantifiers to the beginning. But I'm not clear what the guideline of applying rules is.

Comment: For [PNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conversion_to_prenex_form) use the linked equivalences.

Comment: It seems this book uses an extraordinarily complicated procedure for converting formulas to prenex form. This is probably the result of having "Quant Mvt" rules only for a limited selection of quantifiers and connectives. In practice, one has such rules for lots of connectives and both quantifiers, as in (for example) Smullyan's book "First-Order Logic" (p.117). With these (more precisely, with the fourth rule in Smullyan's list), your exercise takes one step rather than nine.

Comment: Thanks for the recinnebded book！